# Produce plate shape figure

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I want to produce a figure in TiKz like this:

[image]

I tried with this code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[view={60}{30}]
\addplot3[surf,shader=flat,
samples=30,
domain=-1:0,y domain=0:2*pi,
z buffer=sort]
({((1-(x/0.3)) * cos(deg(2*y)))},
{((1-(x/0.3)) * sin(deg(2*y)))},
x);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

which produces:

[image]

It is clear that my code doesn't produce the changes in the angle variations. It doesn't looks like the modal shapes of the annular plate. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, welcome. Note that `pgf` uses degrees for the trig functions, not radians. Do the conversion manually, or try adding `trig format=rad` in the `axis` options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not too difficult to produce something that resembles your desired picture. Apart from changing `trig format`, as suggested by Torbjørn T.), you may want to

- define an appropriate unit vector ratio and
- make the `z` coordinate depend on the angle.

This leads to the proposal:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[view={60}{30},unit vector ratio=1 1 1]
\addplot3[surf,shader=flat,colormap/cool,
samples=30,trig format=rad,
domain=-1:0,y domain=0:2*pi,
z buffer=sort]
({((1-(x/0.3)) * cos(2*y))},
{((1-(x/0.3)) * sin(2*y))},
{x*(1-0.7*cos(4*y))});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, a precise match will require more tuning.

Comment: Thank you so much!. Now I can produce exactly what I want.